# How to allow snake case in spring data rest

Tags: spring-boot

I am sending request to endpoints provided by spring data rest in a spring boot application. But it takes only camel case in request body. How do i send snake case in request body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the following code to your application.properties file

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```

Comment: Please say in what version of Spring Data REST that works. (E.g. I can report that it does not with Spring Boot 2.7.2, which uses Spring 5.3.22 and Spring Data REST 2021.2.2, as the property is simply not known.)